# Stagger call to external page using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, setinterval

I have a large number of function calls that I need to make and I'd like to stagger them so that server load isn't too badly affected.

Basically my site has 8000+ members. I need to loop through each member and for each one run through an array of skills (30 in total) and trigger an external URL that performs a check for each member against each skill.

Something like this:

```
var skills = ['56','79', '92', '118', '129', '134', '363', '364', '365', '367', '362', '368', '66', '84', '120', '123', '136', '359', '137', '142', '155', '176', '165', '168', '171', '174'];

for ( i = 8175; i < 8176; i++){

    setInterval( function (){

        $.each(skills, function (index, value){

            $( "#result" ).load( "/accomplishments/" + value + '/' + i, function( response, status, xhr ) {
                if ( status == "success" ) {

                    var msg = "<p>User: " + i + ' checked for skill ' + value + '</p>';
                    $( "#messages" ).append(msg);
                };
            });
        });

    }, 5000);

}
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of going through the skills array and making a call for each item, send the whole skill list and get back a list of skills the user checked for.

Comment: Why not use AJAX? Just make smaller queries on the Server Side.

Comment: Why not make one request on the server and get it to do the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to run your code 8175 times in five second increments.

Your code should look more like this:

```
var skills = ['56','79', '92', '118', '129', '134', '363', '364', '365', '367', '362', '368', '66', '84', '120', '123', '136', '359', '137', '142', '155', '176', '165', '168', '171', '174'];
var memberId = 1; // assuming id 0 is invalid, we'll start counting on 1
var totalMembers = 8175; // we'll run the code for id 8175, then stop

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {

  $.each(skills, function (index, value){
      $( "#result" ).load( "/accomplishments/" + value + '/' + memberId, function( response, status, xhr ) {
          if ( status == "success" ) {
              var msg = "<p>User: " + memberId + ' checked for skill ' + value + '</p>';
              $( "#messages" ).append(msg);
          };
      });
  });

  memberId += 1;

  if( memberId > totalMembers ) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }

}, 5000);
```